# SQL - get value from another table if column is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'm building matching rules for data reconciliation systems and need your advise on adjusting my sql for it as it currently doesn't return what I need.

There are 2 source tables:

```
      Table X                 Table Y
---------------------         ----------------------
Exec_ID   From  To            Exec_ID     From  To
1         A     B             1           B     C
2         A     B             2           B     C
3         A     B             3           B     C
4         A     B
                              5           B     C
```

Matching conditions are:

```
X.To = Y.From
X.Exec_ID = Y.Exec_ID
```

if there is A -> B and then B -> C, it should return A -> C in the end.

 if there is only A -> B and no further B -> C, it should return A -> B.

So the output should be the following.

```
From    To
---------
A       C
A       C
A       C
A       B
```

SQL I'm using is:

```
select X.From, Y.To
from x
    left outer join y on
    x.To = Y.From
    and x.Exec_ID = y.Exec_ID
```

It returns the values like

```
A C
A C
A C
A Null
```

So the last record is incorrect as it should be A B. Please help to adjust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for null?

```
select X.From, [To] = COALESCE(Y.To, X.To)
from x
    left outer join y on
    x.To = Y.From
    and x.Exec_ID = y.Exec_ID
```

Comment: _from_ is also a keyword that needs to be in brackets.