# SQL Server : is the column value is null get column from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. If percentage in table A is null then I want to look for it in table B

```
SELECT 
    t.id,
    CASE 
       WHEN t.percentage IS NULL
         THEN (SELECT percentage FROM test2 AS s WHERE s.id=t.id )
         ELSE t.percentage
    END AS percentage
FROM
    [project_percentage] t
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - get value from another table if column is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31195207/sql-get-value-from-another-table-if-column-is-null)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT t.id, COALESCE(t.percentage, s.percentage) AS percentage
FROM project_percentage t
LEFT OUTER JOIN
test2 AS s
ON s.id = t.id;
```